# Exporting data from ArcSDE gdb atribute table to file or personal geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, export, file-geodatabase, personal-geodatabase

I'm currently learning GIS and I'm working on a project, I'm doing my own research and trying to accomplish the following with or without Python:

1. Export data from an ArcSDE geodatabase attribute table to a File or Personal Geodatabase OR
2. Export data from an ArcSDE geodatabase attribute table to a dbf table or excel table, then from here I can export it to a personal geodatabase .mdb

Comment: Do you want the *table* from a *feature class*? open in ArcMap, open the attribute table and then on the attribute table select 'export'. You can also use a geoprocessing tool like Table Select to de-spatial the feature class. If you export to a shape file the DBF is there with all the attributes (including shape), open with Excel (but don't save)

Comment: Thanks Michael. Actually, I have a web map and users input data from the web map point features and that data gets saved on the SDE feature class attribute table. I want to be able to export that data with a python script and copy it to a personal geodatabase (.mdb). I want to automate the process.